# Main.Cpp errror. Error 1 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Utilities/Utilities.h': No such file or directory PTPlayer

Tags: include, utilities

How to fix it? This is the error:

```
Main.Cpp errror. Error  1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Utilities/Utilities.h': No such file or directory   PTPlayer
```

I am using ptplayer file, trying to make it to xap fil for windows store app.

Comment: #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// C RunTime Header Files
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "Utilities/Utilities.h"
#include "NlBayes/NlBayes.h"
#include "Utilities/LibImages.h"

using namespace std;

Comment: Is that (part of) your Main.cpp? I'll suggest you post the code in the question instead. Also you should explain more about your setup, e.g. compiler and options used.